# How can'i controle the input format for a field?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I use odoo 9 is I noticed that it does not have a control for the input format for example for the email field I can enter any character and it will consider it as an email address. So I wanted to know how I can control the input format for a field for example for the email field the presence of "@ and the" are mandatory or for the code field VAT for partners the presence of "/" is mandatory .

template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

    <template id="assets_backend" name="stock assets mask ext" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/field_mask/static/src/css/mask.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/field_mask/static/src/js/widgets.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/field_mask/static/src/lib/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</data>
```

partner_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
   <record id="res_partner_view_purchase_buttons_TVA_RC" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">num.TVA.RC.res.partner.view.purchase.</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='website']" position="after">
                        <field name="CodeTVA" select="1" placeholder="Code TVA" widget="mask" data-inputmask-mask="9999999/A/A/A/999" />
                        <field name="RC" select="1" placeholder="Num RC"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
   </record>
</data>
```

widgets.js

```
function openerp_field_mask_widgets(instance) {



    instance.web.form.FieldMask = instance.web.form.FieldChar.extend({
    template : "FieldMask",


    render_value: function() {

        var show_value = this.get_value();
        var field = this;
        if (!field.get("effective_readonly")) {

            field.$el.find('input').val(show_value);

            var mask = field.node.attrs.mask;
            field.$el.find('input').inputmask(mask);


        } else {

              field.$(".oe_form_char_content").text(show_value);

        }


    },


    get_value: function() {
        val = this.get('value');
        if (!val) {
            return '';
        }

        return  val;
    },

});

instance.web.form.widgets.add('mask', 'instance.web.form.FieldMask');
 }

  openerp.field_mask = function(openerp) {
openerp.field_mask = openerp.field_mask || {};
openerp_field_mask_widgets(openerp);
 }
```

Comment: Check the `@api.constrains` decorator. Creating your checking method with that decorator is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own widget with inputMask by inheriting `FieldChar` and you can find usefull mudules at [odoowidgets](https://github.com/gilvanleal/odoowidgets.git) or [field_mask](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/field_mask/)

Comment: i have created my field with the mask but there is no diffrence  **<field name="CodeTVA" select="1" placeholder="Code TVA" widget="mask" data-inputmask-mask="9999999/A/A/A/999" />**

Comment: Sorry i thought it was modified

Comment: Use `mask` instead of `data-inputmask-mask`.